# how to set EOT as line separator for Spring batch file processing

Tags: spring, file, spring-batch, delimiter

I have a requirement to process a file that has an EOT character as the end of the record but not a newline. I am using spring batch processing for bulk processing. I not able to set EOT with hex value "\u0004" as the end of line character for processing

AP01000110319.99RD34/78 OPTIMA BAT  0110000000100****AU0081140500003001000110

Those characters are not visible. It's basically EOT (end of transmission character).

My code looks something like this

```
public FlatFileItemReader<ProductDTO> productReader() throws Exception 

{
    FlatFileItemReader<ProductDTO> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    reader.setResource(inputFileResource(null));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<ProductDTO>() {{
                    setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5", "field6","field7", "field8", "field9", "field10" ,"field11" );
            setDelimiter("\u001c");
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new ProductFileRowMapper());
    }});
    reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy("\u0004")
    {});
    return reader;
```

I tried setting DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy but it does not work. Basically I am looking at how to set any character other than newline as a line separator. My input file is a single line large file with each record separated by an EOT. Any help here appreciated.

Comment: `I tried setting DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy but it does not work.`: You are creating a `new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy("\u0004")` but the parameter here is a `quoteCharacter` not a delimiter. Have you tried to use a `SuffixRecordSeparatorPolicy` with a suffix set to `\u0004`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It worked for me

Comment: Great to hear it helped. I added an answer for that, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried setting DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy but it does not work.

You are creating a new `DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy("\u0004")` but the parameter here is a `quoteCharacter` and not a delimiter. You need to use a `SuffixRecordSeparatorPolicy` with a suffix set to `\u0004`.